# How to interpret this sentence

Tags: meaning

"The after-dinner treat I like most to eat is a slice of warm cherry pie."

In this sentence, I don't know the meaning of "treat".
(The after-dinner treat)  ➡️ is it correct expression?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. One of our requirements for posting a question about meaning in context is to first look up the word in a dictionary. Questions without basic research are subject to close for low quality.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's correct.

[**Treat**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/treat):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>
> **2** : an especially unexpected source of joy, delight, or amusement ·  seeing her again was a *treat*
>
> We took the kids to the water park as a special *treat*.
> cookies and other tasty *treats*
> She rewarded the dog with a *treat*.

In the case of cherry pie as an *after-dinner treat*, the treat happens to be dessert.